# Power BI :: how to compare 2 columns on 2 different Timelines?

Tags: powerbi, dax, visualization, powerbi-desktop

I've been trying to follow [this guide](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hu_fOtZDJwU) that tells me how to compare two columns but it just doesn't work for my scenario.

This is what I have right now:

[image]

And you can download it here:

- [.pbix](https://1drv.ms/u/s!ArldK_gE2gPUkcwioDIJzDoA4hiIJA?e=TAvI2p)
- [.xlsx](https://1drv.ms/x/s!ArldK_gE2gPUkcwhkUIUR5Bz9ZjXcg?e=z2UFhQ)

My goal is:

1. to have a second Timesline so I can show another month
2. that should manage the second column which is the same as the `Sum of Cost` but this time for another month
3. a third column so I can show the difference

sort of this:

[image]

I tried to create a copy of the same table but the two Timeline get in conflict and once you choose a month on the first Timeline you can only choose the same month on the second Timeline.

I suspect that what I miss is a [Calendar table](https://www.techrepublic.com/article/create-date-table-microsoft-power-bi/) but I tried that pattern too and I had always the same problem.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Testing in a few hours, darling. <3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are the steps.

Create one calendar table as follows:

```
Calendar 1 = CALENDARAUTO()
```

Create a second calendar table as follows:

```
Calendar 2 = CALENDARAUTO()
```

You will now have this. Make sure there are no relationships.

[image]

Add two timelines and in the field well, drag date from calendar 1 into timeline 1 and date from calendar 2 into timeline 2.

The timelines will show all dates. To fix this, create two measures as follows:

```
Fact Count 1 = CALCULATE( COUNTROWS(Data), TREATAS(VALUES('Calendar 1'[Date]), Data[UsageDate])) 

Fact Count 2 = CALCULATE( COUNTROWS(Data), TREATAS(VALUES('Calendar 2'[Date]), Data[UsageDate]))
```

On each timeline, in the filter panel drag the **relevant** measure in there as follows and set as follows:

[image]

You should be at this stage now.

[image]

Create 3 new measures and drag them to your table.

```
Cost Month 1 = CALCULATE(SUM(Data[Cost] ) ,TREATAS(VALUES('Calendar 1'[Date]), Data[UsageDate]))

Cost Month 2 = CALCULATE(SUM(Data[Cost] ) ,TREATAS(VALUES('Calendar 2'[Date]), Data[UsageDate]))

Delta = [Cost Month 2] - [Cost Month 1]
```

You should be left with this:

[image]

Comment: Hi David and thank you for your help. The measures are created but apparently I cannot put them inside the Timeline. Do you know why? https://snipboard.io/nsTDFa.jpg

Comment: Measures don't go in the timelines. Read the instructions again as the measures will go in the filter panel for each timeline

Comment: We are firing rounds of AK-47 out of the window. Thank you so much David Bacci

Comment: Lol - glad you got it sorted Francesco

Answer (score 0):

First populate 'Month Name' column using Power Query

[image]

Then write measures

```
Cost_Feb = CALCULATE(SUM(Data[Cost]), FILTER(Data, Data[Month Name] = "February"))

Cost_March = CALCULATE(SUM(Data[Cost]), FILTER(Data, Data[Month Name] = "March"))

Diff = [Cost_March] - [Cost_Feb]
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry but I cannot use this solution for every month. What if I need to compare two different weeks?