# Issue adding a dynamic parameter to a Power BI report and stopping a table list filtering out the visuals

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I have the following Measure in PBI:

```
Count of New Computers = calculate(
DISTINCTCOUNT('tblComputer'[Computer]),
filter(
    'tblComputer',
    'tblComputer'[YearMonth]="2023-04"
    && not('tblComputer'[Computer] in 
    
    CALCULATETABLE(
       values( 'tblComputer'[Computer]),
        filter('tblComputer','tblComputer'[YearMonth]="2023-03")
))))
```

This looks at **tblComputer** which has two columns, **Computer** and **YearMonth**.

The measure counts the number of computers that are in the list with **MonthDate** = **"2023-04"** but were not listed in the previous month: **MonthDate** = **"2023-03"**.

Effectively telling me which new computers have been added to the list.

I want to make this dynamic, so that the viewer can select the distinct list of **YearMonth** to specify the 2 specific months they'd like to compare against each other (2 separate select lists).

My problem is, when I add a table to the PowerBI screen, and drag **YearMonth** to it, each time I select a YearMonth from the table list, then it immediately filters out all other data on the screen, that doesn't have a YearMonth of that selected in the table.

Is there a way to stop this default behaviour, so that I can just reference the two table selections (Month1 and Month 2) in the measures?

Thanks for any help,

Mark

Comment: I've literally just answered the same question here. Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76074841/power-bi-how-to-compare-2-columns-on-2-different-timelines/76091405#76091405

Comment: Hi David - almost, but my "YearMonth" columns are calculated columns, which are just text as "YYYY-MM" (taken from a full UTC date/time field which is different for every entry, so I extrapolated a field just to show the YearMonth.

Comment: The pattern is the exact same - you just need two disconnected tables to drive your slicers and then use the values in your measures.