# Power BI: Using Slicers to Choose Which Measure to Display

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery, powerbi-desktop, powerpivot

I've been outrageously [helped by David Bacci](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76074841/power-bi-how-to-compare-2-columns-on-2-different-timelines) for a dashboard that helped me compare one date range to another.

The hardest part is done for now and we are quite happy with the results.

However I need to see the same data in 4 different way. If you look at this image I have 4 tables and the only thing that I want to change is the first column:

[image]

I don't want to show 4 different tables. It looks ugly!

I would like to have a dropdown menu or a filter that allows me to show only 1 table and switch the first column.

The methods that I found online to archive this are:

- http://breaking-bi.blogspot.com/2016/06/power-bipowerpivot-using-slicers-to.html
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wcNYHmCMEuA

But the look very archaic to me.

Are these really the only way to switch a column in a table?

Is there any alternative?

You can download a sample of my work here:

- [.pbix](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1o7OejVh3VSQriJtFfk5_UUZQxvTEaoiK/view?usp=sharing)
- [.xlsx](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1OrXh6fTLUuKTdIV24xt8HMiuR0hyc9Px/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=104282656744911725593&rtpof=true&sd=true)

Your help will be much appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are the steps for you.

On the ribbon select Modelling -> New Parameter -> Fields

Complete as follows:

[image]

Delete 3 of your 4 tables. In the remaining table, delete the first column and replace with the newly created parameter column.

[image]

Use the slicer to change which column is now shown first. Enjoy ;).

Comment: Is this a new feature? Why all online documentation pointed me in the wrong direction?

Comment: Yes, a new feature. PBI gets new features every month. Some of the old blogs are still relevant as this new feature doesn't do everything that you could do the old way.