# Power BI :: line chart based on two different date range

Tags: powerbi, dax, visualization, powerbi-desktop, data-modeling

Not sure if this is possible.

I have a dashboards that compares [2 different date ranges](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76074841/power-bi-how-to-compare-2-columns-on-2-different-timelines).

I have created a Line Chart based on the first calendar and first costs of the month:

[image]

Now I would like to add a second line but that line is based on a different calendar.

And there is no second X-axis to add.

Is this possible?

I tried [this solution](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=95rfK8-KMwA) but it cannot apply to me.

Files are here:

- [.pbix](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1kRuUJewr8C0aCKREukcD9a3odgN6USE-/view?usp=sharing)
- [.xlsx](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1OrXh6fTLUuKTdIV24xt8HMiuR0hyc9Px/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=104282656744911725593&rtpof=true&sd=true)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE2**

In settings, uncheck the following.

[image]

Create the calendar table as follows to add all your columns you will need (you can add more later).

```
Calendar = 

ADDCOLUMNS (
        CALENDARAUTO( ),
    "Calendar Year", "CY " & YEAR ( [Date] ),
    "Month Name", FORMAT ( [Date], "mmmm" ),
    "Month Number", MONTH ( [Date] ),
    "Weekday", FORMAT ( [Date], "dddd" ),
    "Weekday number", WEEKDAY( [Date] ),
    "Quarter", "Q" & TRUNC ( ( MONTH ( [Date] ) - 1 ) / 3 ) + 1)
```

Create a relationship between new calendar table and data table.

[image]

Change your measures as follows:

From

```
MoM Month to Date = 
CALCULATE(
    SUM(Data[Cost]),
    DATESMTD(Data[UsageDate].[Date]))
```

To

```
MoM Month to Date = 
CALCULATE(
    SUM(Data[Cost]),
    DATESMTD('Calendar'[Date]))
```

**UPDATE**

How about this?

[image]

If so, just make the field well of the visual contain day only like this:

[image]

Do you mean like this?

[image]

If so, create a new calendar table

```
Calendar = CALENDARAUTO()
```

Join to your Data table as a 1 to many.

[image]

Use the date field from the new calendar table in the x axis.

[image]

Comment: Hi, I forgot to tell that the lines must be one upon another. Not sure if that can be possible

Comment: Not sure what you mean? If the months are different, how would they be overlaid?

Comment: Do you mean you want day 1 of month 1 at the same point as day 1 of month 2 etc?

Comment: Nah, is more difficult than that. Because as you made the 2 calendars, as you can see, you might select 20 days with one calendar and 30 says with the other. And I'm not sure how the two lines will be have in that way. 
Maybe is just not doable.

Comment: It's certainly doable with a Mont over Month calculation, like in the video. Or with YoY or WoW or QoQ. But given the fact that we have 2 different calendars I don't know.

Comment: Maybe the two lines should just start on the same point and then if with one calendar you select 7 days and with the second you select 30 days... well, simply one line will be shorter. And it's up to the user to be careful and select 30 days with both calendars

Comment: I'll update with something now

Comment: mmm... that was overwhelmingly easy. I will check tomorrow. Thank you for you help. You should have a URL where people can tip you with PayPal. You are helping me so much

Comment: Not a bad idea lol. I've updated my profile.

Comment: It's interesting, as soon as I create the calendar all measures that I created manually brakes: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1GN_y4-e5vfsdz7yS_PdA97JwLf9gS9p9/view?usp=sharing . The error says `Column reference to 'date' in table 'Usage details' cannot be used with a variation 'Date' because it does not have any.`

Comment: I think this is the result of introducing a proper calendar table. Can you post one of the measures that is going wrong. You can't use .day etc and must create a proper calendar table if you go this route (which is standard good practice anyway)

Comment: Make sure to turn OFF auto time intelligence in the settings. Thanks by the way for the donation - that's very kind

Comment: You can't use .[month], .[day] or .[quarter] for instance. You would just have these as columns in your new calendar table.

Comment: Cool ,I updated the .pbix and if you download it now you will find the Measure Table with a MoM Month to Date column. That column brakes as soon as you create a calendar and you link it to the Data table

Comment: I'll update the answer now.

Comment: It worked. Is it standard good practice to create so many calendars? When I see your dashboards on LinkedIn do they all have all these custom measure under the hood?

Comment: Each model depends on the use case. You should always disable in built calendars and always create a custom calendar table. Your other two calendars are merely to drive two slicers for a very specific requirement and because they're disconnected, are nothing to worry about anyway.

Comment: I have a problem with all the metrics you made for me few weeks ago. The fixed amount is starting from 0. Which is strange, I changed the date to the 1th of February and the fixed amount should be 115.79 https://snipboard.io/T6DZwq.jpg . I'm not in a rush

Comment: Might be an idea to start a fresh question. I don't have the old file so you'll need to supply one to debug.

Comment: I found the solution, no problem

Comment: Hi @David, I noticed that when I compare 2 months against 2 month the line chart is still based on 30 days. https://snipboard.io/AaYime.jpg . each line is now based on the sum of 2 days. Do you think it's fixable? Do you want me to open another question?

Comment: Yes, upload a file and explain the problem from scratch in another question.

Comment: Every now and then I come back to this reply and I cannot stop thinking about the beauty of it. I read it again and again. It's like watching Dr. Pimple video's:  I just cannot stop.

Comment: Lol - I forgot all about this.